# How to disable ViewPager swipe but enable tap and let view still process input?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I'm trying to make a viewpager that doesn't swipe but also allows touch inputs in the view it is showing to receive them.

When I return true in    onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent() then the buttons in the view it's showing don't work.

Comment: If you don't want swiping,you should use tab widget instead

Comment: Why are you using a `ViewPager` here?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm making a Tutorial screen with 7 pages. Should I use a tabWidget without the tabs, or just fragments?

Comment: That's a question of how the user is going to navigate. Usually, when I think "tutorial screen", the UI either allows swipes or offers wizard-style forward/next buttons. Since you don't want swipes and you don't want tabs, and you don't mention any other navigation, I don't know how the user will get past the first page.

Comment: @CommonsWare On the first screen the user will press a "next" button and on the other screens they will tap the right half of screen to go forward and left half of screen to go back.

Comment: Um, OK. I'm not sure how users are going to know to do that right half/left half stuff. If you want a wizard, [use a wizard](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=wizard). Beyond that, you could use fragments directly, with `replace()` `FragmentTransaction` operations to switch screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Wizard like https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/Wizard helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling swipe entirely **doesn't seem to give a good user experience**. But that's just my personal opinion.

But if I were in your place and wanted to provide a **cutting-edge wizard style tutorial page**, I would have surely used this - [ProductTour](https://github.com/matrixxun/ProductTour).

This library is just amazing and I actually use it.